# Conectar mi back de node.js con Google Identity

Tags: nodejs, express, backend, google-api

Estoy intentando conectar mi back con google identity, para iniciar sesión con google. Tengo mi servidor de node y en el public del servidor de node tengo un **`index.html`** que estoy visualizando en `http://localhost:8080`, cree mi *Oauth 2.0* con sus respectivas credenciales y en los orígenes autorizados de Javascript tengo como uri 1 `http://localhost` y como uri 2 `http://localhost:8080`.

Al abrir el localhost, me aparece el botón de *identity*, al tocarlo se abre el *popup* de inicio de sesión de google pero en la consola me aparece este error:

> client:257 Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy policy would block the window.postMessage call.
> Qp @ client:257
> (anonymous) @ client:238
> kc @ client:59
> b @ client:56

Les dejo mi **`index.html`**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta
      http-equiv="Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy"
      content="same-origin-allow-popups"
    />
    <title>Google Sign-in</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Sign in with Google</h1>
    <hr />
    <html>
      <body>
        <script
          src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client"
          async
          defer
        ></script>
        <div
          id="g_id_onload"
          data-client_id="MI ID CLIENT VA ACÁ"
          data-callback="handleCredentialResponse"
          data-auto_prompt="false"
          data-auto_select="true"
        ></div>
        <div
          class="g_id_signin"
          data-type="standard"
          data-size="large"
          data-theme="outline"
          data-text="sign_in_with"
          data-shape="rectangular"
          data-logo_alignment="left"
        ></div>
        <script>
          function handleCredentialResponse(response) {
            // decodeJwtResponse() is a custom function defined by you
            // to decode the credential response.
            console.log(response.credential);
          }
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
  </body>
</html>
```

y también les dejo mi servidor de express:

```
import express from "express";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import cors from "cors";
import userRouter from "../routes/usuarios.js";
import authRouter from "../routes/auth.js";
import { dbConnection } from "../database/config.js";
dotenv.config();

export class Server {
  constructor() {
    this.app = express();
    this.port = process.env.PORT;
    //Paths
    this.usuariosPath = "/api/usuarios";
    this.authPath = "/api/auth";

    // Conectar DB
    this.conectarDB();
    //Middleware
    this.middlewares();
    //Rutas de mi aplicación
    this.routes();
  }

  async conectarDB() {
    await dbConnection();
  }

  middlewares() {
    //CORS
    this.app.use(cors());

    this.app.use((req, res, next) => {
      res.header("Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy", "same-origin-allow-popups");
      next();
    });

    //Lectura y parseo del body
    this.app.use(express.json());
    //Directorio publico
    this.app.use(express.static("public"));
  }
  routes() {
    this.app.use(this.authPath, authRouter);
    this.app.use(this.usuariosPath, userRouter);
  }

  listen() {
    this.app.listen(this.port, () => {
      console.log(`Servidor escuchando en el puerto ${this.port}`);
    });
  }
}
```

Probé utilizando en mi servidor de node este middleware:

```
this.app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy", "same-origin-allow-popups");
  next();
});
```

y en el **`index.html`** este meta:

```
<meta
  http-equiv="Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy"
  content="same-origin-allow-popups"
/>
```

Pero no tengo resultado, si alguien puede ayudarme estaría muy agradecido.

Comment: Es del curso de Node de cero a experto? Quita el `res.header` así como el `<meta>`, agrega el código de tu helper, probablemente te falte algo para que te deje usar la verificación.